# Related post by category reture this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in

Tags: php, wordpress

I got this code from this [site](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/09/display-related-posts-thumbnails-wordpress-plugin/) on how to display related post by category but when I paste it to my theme it return me this error.

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampp\htdocs\mm\wp-content\themes\mm\single.php on line 61`

```
<?php $orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
if ($categories) {
$category_ids = array();
foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
$args=array(
'category__in' => $category_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=> 5, // Number of related posts that will be displayed.
'caller_get_posts'=>1,
'orderby'=>'rand' // Randomize the posts
);
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<div id="related_posts" class="clear"><h3>Related Posts</h3><ul>';
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post(); ?>
<li>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
 <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'related-posts' ); ?>
 </a>
 <div class="related_content">
 <a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 </div>
</li>
<? }
echo '</ul></div>';
} }
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code indentation is the key, as a tip try alternative control statements
Try to adapt a coding standard to avoid further problems in the future, also don`t use short tags, you might migrate the code on a server which isn't configured accordingly

```
<?php
    $orig_post = $post;
    global $post;
    $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if ($categories):
        $category_ids = array();
        foreach($categories as $individual_category) 
        {
            $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
        }
        $args=array(
        'category__in' => $category_ids,
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'posts_per_page'=> 5, // Number of related posts that will be displayed.
        'caller_get_posts'=>1,
        'orderby'=>'rand' // Randomize the posts
        );
        $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ):
            echo '<div id="related_posts" class="clear"><h3>Related Posts</h3><ul>';
            while( $my_query->have_posts() ):
                $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                 <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'related-posts' ); ?>
                 </a>
                 <div class="related_content">
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                 </div>
                </li>
                <?php
            endwhile;
            ?> 
            </ul></div>
            <?php
        endif;
    endif;
    $post = $orig_post;
    wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Comment: thank yo so much for this working code by the way which line i mis? hope you have time to drop your comment here. thank's

Comment: I have no clue...I rewrote it as mentioned (no short tags, indentation-I know it can be a burden but try to implement this as a best practice) and had no issues, but I think it was the short opening tag after closing the <li> tag

Comment: I configured my IDE to make 4 spaces instead of tabs and UNIX line ending for files :)